# Rails: Is there a way to see which view/partial produced which part of the site's HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

In our application we are working with a lot of variations of similar views/partials. Sometimes it's a bit difficult to find the right file when you want to edit it. So it would be really handy to somehow print out the view's/partial's filepaths in the generated HTML code.

I guess one could overwrite the `render` method for this, but maybe there's already a solution for this?

Thanks a lot for help
Josh

Comment: Adding info in HTML comments would be a good idea indeed. I can't help about how to do it, but I would strongly advise not to mention filenames or path. The less info on your file structure/site architecture you give, the more your app is secure.

Comment: The development logs will show all the partials used to render the page rt?

Answer (score 0):

You can see all rendered views/partials on `console log` or in `development log`

and it looks like this:

```
 Rendered static/_menu.html.erb (165.0ms)
```